# How to allow other users to call your script and write to the protected range of the Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Spreadsheet App which has protected ranges. With my own account, I have created the script which reads and modifies data in it. Now want to allow other users to run the script with their accounts. Is any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually realised that my question was not proper one. Once the other user doesn't have permissions to a certain range that means the script doesn't have the permission once the session runs under the customer's privileges.

So, the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow these users to edit the range.

You have to go to change permissions > Restrict who can edit this range > Custom

[image]